# Make a read-only OS image from working installation

Tags: operating-systems, filesystem

I currently have a working Raspbian installation on my Raspberry Pi that I use to read my car's diagnostic info using OBD2 (by setting up a Wifi hotspot on boot and opening a socket relaying data to an OBD serial interface)

However, I can't properly shut down the Pi, because it runs off the car's 12V. So in order to prevent filesystem corruption I would like to make the OS read-only.

I didn't find anything useful on Google unfortunately. I'd like to have something working like a live CD (squashFS image). Can I just make a squashFS image of my current root partition?

What about log files and such? Do I need to have some kind of RAM filesystem for the system temp files or something?

Comment: You might consider exploring Pi TinyCore Linux which is read only by default, and more appropriate for what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run Arch Linux on Pi, I had to change a few things to get it to run fine with the file system mounted as ro.

I followed this [blog](http://ruiabreu.org/2013-06-02-booting-raspberry-pi-in-readonly.html) to setup everything, check it out.

I understand that arch and debian and quite different in startup scripts but it might be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about adding a sense wire to the Acc of the car and a script watching it on a GPIO pin to detect when it's shutting off and run "sudo shutdown -h now" with a diode & capacitor after the sensor to supply just enough power to give it adequate time to power down safely before its drained.

Comment: Thank you but it seems a bit much as I really don't need a read/write system for my application.